# Android HashMap Serialization / Deserialization

Tags: android, bitmap, hashmap, save

Hello I have a Hasmap of bitmaps which I need to store on the Android device to be used when next the application starts.

My hashmap looks like this, and contains up to 1000 Bitmaps:

```
private static HashMap <String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
```

Comment: would be interested in the same uqestions..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider create extension of Map (by using AbstractMap) and override the related functions. In general the structure of the extension should have:

1. An in memory hard cache using regular Map. This should be a size bound cache object. You could leverage LinkedHashMap and override removeEldesEntry() to check if the size is exceeded

```
    this.objectMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap()  {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry  eldest) {
            if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
                // remove from cache, pass to secondary SoftReference cache or directly to the disk
            }
        }
    });
```

1. If the cache is exceeded, then put it to disk
2. Override the get function to do the following : On initial get, load the bitmap from disk based on certain naming convention (related to the key) and store it in memory. Roughly something like (please forgive any syntax error)

```
    @Override
    public Bitmap get(Object key) {
        if(key != null) {
            // first level, hard cache
            if(objectMap.containsKey(key)) {
                return objectMap.get(key);
            }

            // soft reference cache
            if(secondaryCache.containsKey(key)) {
                return secondaryCache.get(key);
            }

            // get from disk if it is not in hard or soft cache
            String fileName = "Disk-" + key + ".txt";
            File f = new File(cacheDir, fileName);

            if(f.exists()) {
                // put this back to the hard cache
                Bitmap object = readFromReader(f);

                if(object != null) {
                    objectMap.put((String)key, object);
                    return object;
                }
            }
        }


        return null;  // unable to get from any data source
    }
```

Similarly your put has to be override to put to the disk for later use, so when you reinitialize your app you could just create an instance of the map extension. If you want, you could also preload the hashmap by most recently used items in the app. Basically, by extending the AbstractMap, you get the flexibilities without killing your memory with that 1000 bitmaps. Hope this helps